# Unable to get all user list from the azure ad using Microsoft graph API

Tags: python, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

I have a `python` code which gets all the user from the `azure ad`. Below is the code:

```
import http.client
import json 
import requests


def get_token():
    r = requests.post("https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + "<tenant_id>" + "/oauth2/token",
        data={"grant_type": "client_credentials",
                "client_secret": "<client_secret>",
                "client_id": "<client_id>",
                "resource": "https://graph.microsoft.com"})
    ret_body = r.json()
    return ret_body['access_token']
    

token = get_token()
headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token}
conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection('graph.microsoft.com')
conn.request("GET", "/v1.0/users", "", headers)
response = conn.getresponse()
data = response.read()
data = data.decode('utf-8')
data = json.loads(data)
print(len(data['value']))
```

When I run the above code I am getting proper response and all the data. But some of the users are not present. Its only returning the data till the names with `K` and some of the names which are starting with `S` are not present in the data. I am also checking the length of the users list and it is always 100 while total number of users added are 178

[image]

I am not sure the why the API is only returning 100 users list and not the complete 178 users. Can anyone please give me any idea what is wrong with code or the API. Please help. Thanks

Comment: Maybe it only returned the first page? Docs on paging: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/paging?context=graph%2Fapi%2F1.0&view=graph-rest-1.0

Comment: @juunas Thanks it worked. Please answer the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Graph API will return the first 100 users on the first page by default.
You need to request the next pages, docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/paging?context=graph%2Fapi%2F1.0&view=graph-rest-1.0.

A `@odata.nextLink` property is returned in the response, you can request that to get the next page.